# ExpandableListView OnChildClickListener doesn't work

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

**Adapter**

```
 public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

     private Context mContext;
     private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
     private List <Grupe> mGroupCollection;
     private int[] groupStatus;


     public ExpandableListAdapter() {}
     public ExpandableListAdapter(Context pContext,
         ExpandableListView pExpandableListView,
         List <Grupe> pGroupCollection) {
         mContext = pContext;
         mGroupCollection = pGroupCollection;
         mExpandableListView = pExpandableListView;
         groupStatus = new int[mGroupCollection.size()];

         setListEvent();
     }

     private void setListEvent() {

         mExpandableListView
             .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {
                     groupStatus[arg0] = 1;
                 }
             });

         mExpandableListView
             .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onGroupCollapse(int arg0) {
                     groupStatus[arg0] = 0;
                 }
             });
     }

     @Override
     public String getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
         return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getChildren().get(arg0).getPrimaoc_Poruke();
     }

     @Override
     public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
         return 0;
     }

     @Override
     public View getChildView(int arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, View arg3,
         ViewGroup arg4) {

         ChildHolder childHolder;
         if (arg3 == null) {
             arg3 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                 R.layout.list_group_item, null);

             childHolder = new ChildHolder();

             childHolder.title = (TextView) arg3.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
             arg3.setTag(childHolder);
         } else {
             childHolder = (ChildHolder) arg3.getTag();
         }

         childHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getChildren().get(arg1).getPrimaoc_Poruke());
         return arg3;
     }

     @Override
     public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
         return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getChildren().size();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
         return mGroupCollection.get(arg0);
     }

     @Override
     public int getGroupCount() {
         return mGroupCollection.size();
     }

     @Override
     public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
         return arg0;
     }

     @Override
     public View getGroupView(int arg0, boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {

         GroupHolder groupHolder;
         if (arg2 == null) {
             arg2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
             groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
             groupHolder.img = (ImageView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.tag_img);
             groupHolder.title = (TextView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.group_title);
             arg2.setTag(groupHolder);
         } else {
             groupHolder = (GroupHolder) arg2.getTag();
         }

         if (groupStatus[arg0] == 0) {
             groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
         } else {
             groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
         }

         groupHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).getTip());

         return arg2;
     }

     class GroupHolder {
         ImageView img;
         TextView title;
     }

     class ChildHolder {
         TextView title;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean hasStableIds() {
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

**MainActivity**

```
 public class Glavna extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnChildClickListener {

     private List <Grupe> mGroupCollection;
     private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
     private ExpandableListAdapter adapter = null;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_glavna);
         prepareResource();
         initPage();
     }

     private void initPage() {
         mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
         adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,mExpandableListView, mGroupCollection);
         mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
         mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

     }
     
     private void prepareResource() {
         mGroupCollection = new ArrayList <Grupe> ();
         ge.setTip("Online korisnici");
         mGroupCollection.add(ge);

         AktivniChat gi = new AktivniChat(1, "receiver 1", new Korisnik(1, "sender1"));
         mGroupCollection.get(0).setAktivniChat(gi);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set  **android:focusable="false"** on all elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" 
    android:focusable="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupItem"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF385"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:focusable="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FF84"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="sample"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Worked for me, anyone knows why ? Is this a bug ?

Comment: This isn't a bug as far as I know. The views inside the childView simply catch the onClick() event an thus the event never reaches the childView. (And that's ehy the onChildClickListener never geht's called)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to enable child Selectable property..

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me too... All items in layout (of the child) must be set to focusable="false" and clickable="false". But if you have buttons in child layout this will not work.